# Event listener for mmenu counter

Tags: jquery, counter, mmenu

I am using the mmenu plugin for building an app like page. (Link - http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/)

On the advanced page, (http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/mmenu-3.0.2/docs/examples/advanced.html), if i add an `li` to the option `Work Colleagues` and hide it using inline style `display:none`, the counter still increases by one, which isn't ideal.

Is there any event listener / events which can allow this, programatically updating the menus and keep the correct count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin will count all LIs (visible or not) that does not have one of these classes:

1. mm-label
2. mm-subtitle
3. mm-noresults
4. mm-noresult

The first 3 are used by the plugin for visual purposes, the fourth (mm-noresult) is used to hide it from the search results. So instead of adding display: none, you should add class="mm-noresult".

To update the counters, trigger their "count" custom event:

```
$("#menu em").trigger( "count" );
```

Regards, Fred

Comment: That helps a lot. Thanks a ton and thanks again for the great plugin.